# How to write or append to text file using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, file-io, sqlcmd

i need to call sqlcmd from stored procedure to export table to text file?

Comment: +1 for the pic.
Check this link
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by the following way you can do this

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo pranay test application > d:\file.txt'
```

more about this : http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-copy-data-append-data-into-files-

Comment: i can't append to file like this

Comment: The > redirect overwrites, >> will append

Comment: Guess i'm making an easy mistake, but the file is looking like chinese characters instead of the simple `"test"` i am echoing-in.